# Using ReactiveSearch with plain elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I'd like to use reactivesearch with my own plain vanilla elasticsearch cluster. While the example and documentation describe that this should be possible: [ReactiveBase](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html), see the `url` Param. I get connection errors and a Websocket call `wss://..` which looks like `ReactiveBase` is trying to connect to a `appbase.io` hosted elastic instead. It also passes a credentials code along with the call to elastic which is not specified in my code.

Is it possible to connect to a normal elastic and where can I find the documentation on how to do this?

This is my definition of `ReactiveBase`:

```
<ReactiveBase app="documents"url="https://search-siroop-3jjelqkbvwhzqzsolxt5ujxdxm.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/">
```

[image: Connection Errors]

To implement this example I followed the [ReactiveSearch Quickstart](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivesearch.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to connect to a normal Elasticsearch cluster [(docs)](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html#connect-to-elasticsearch) with reactivesearch. It seems you're using the correct props. Sample code:

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="your-elasticsearch-index"
  url="http://your-elasticsearch-cluster"
>
    <Component1 .. />
    <Component2 .. />
</ReactiveBase>
```

The `app` prop refers to the index name. Looks like you're using this with AWS. Since AWS doesn't allow you to configure ES settings, you might need to use a middleware proxy server. From the [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html#connect-to-elasticsearch):

> If you are using Elasticsearch on AWS, then the recommended approach
>   is to connect via the middleware proxy as they don’t allow setting the
>   Elasticsearch configurations.

The docs also explain how you can write your own proxy server.

**TLDR:**

- [Proxy server](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-server)
- Using the proxy server in [client app](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-client) with reactivesearch

The connection error related to websockets you see here isn't causing the issue. It's used for streaming which works on appbase.io. This has been fixed in the `2.2.0` release. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you please help me to connect to my Elasticsearch AWS cluster @Divyanshu ? I dont find so much information or examples about it... In my ReactiveBase I have add the app='my-index' and in the url I put the cluster url, but I cant get the information of the indexed documents and I dont have errors in the console.

Comment: Hi, last I remember, the connection should work with just the `app` and `url` prop. Could you please share a codesandbox example if you want me to take a look or perhaps someone in the [gitter](https://gitter.im/appbaseio/reactivesearch) channel

Comment: Hi @Divyanshu , Thanks! This is my codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/kmj2q5n2vr?fontsize=14

Comment: Hey @Laura the app is working fine. Just remove the `autosuggest={false}` prop in `DataSearch` and you should be able to see the suggestions.

Comment: Oh...thanks so much @Divyanshu  ! Just another question please! Do you know why this is not working? https://codesandbox.io/s/kmj2q5n2vr ? It works fine if I delete ResultCard component

Comment: Seems like you're using a newer version which has a different API. For example the `onData` prop has been removed it seems. Could you please check from the docs? I'm not aware of the new API either.

Comment: I have seen this, which was published 5 days ago: https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/885 But I Dont know how to change my package.json to achieve this goal : https://codesandbox.io/s/kmj2q5n2vr

Comment: You can just change the dependency version in package.json

Comment: It works, @Divyanshu. Thanks! Can you please take a last view to my code? https://codesandbox.io/s/3401jp81pm  I have added a Reactivemaps component but it does not work. Im sorry for all these questions...