# reactivesearch - reactivebase with AWS

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, reactivesearch

[Using ReactiveSearch with plain elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425563/using-reactivesearch-with-plain-elasticsearch)

this above link as well as appbase.io briefly talks how to connect reactivebase with elasticsearch that runs on AWS. can someone provide more details on how to do that?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ReactiveSearch with plain elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425563/using-reactivesearch-with-plain-elasticsearch)